3 series with 2 scales not working - ApexCharts
I have 3 series, 2 similars and 1 different :

serie 1 - similar to serie2
serie 2 - similar to serie1
serie 3

Goal :
My goal is to group "serie 1" and "serie 2" on the same yaxis and have another yaxis with "serie 3" because it's data is not similar to serie 1 or serie 2.
So I tried with the following docs : https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/multiple-yaxis-scales/
Current issue :
serie1 and serie2 are well grouped in my code, but only serie1 is displayed on the chart. serie3 is correctly working on it's own yaxis.

Reproduce issue :
Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hxep2x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Thanks for your help

first arrange the services


series.map((m, index) => {
      if (m.prices && m.prices.length > 0) {
        return { name: m.name, data: m.prices, color: this.colors[index] };
      }
    });



then uncomment this


this.chart.updateOptions({ yaxis: this.getYAxisNotGrouped() });




It's indeed working, but my goal is to use this.chart.updateOptions({ yaxis: this.getYAxisNotGrouped() }); to group serie11 and serie12 on the same axes

ok ,so for that first group the series like
const group1 = ['serie11', 'serie12'];     const group2 = ['serie13'];
then config the ranges with this groups like:
const ranges = selectedNodes.map((m) => {       const values = m.prices;       return {         name: m.name,         min: values.length > 0 ? Math.min(...values) : 0,         max: values.length > 0 ? Math.max(...values) : 0,       };     });

in return merge it like
{         seriesName: group1,         title: {           text: 'Series 1 & 2',           style: {             fontSize: '12px',             fontWeight: '400',           },         },         min: Math.min(...ranges.filter((r) => group1.includes(r.name)).map(r => r.min)),         max: Math.max(...ranges.filter((r) => group1.includes(r.name)).map(r => r.max)),         tickAmount: 5,         labels: {           formatter: (value) => parseFloat(value?.toFixed(4)),         },       },
hope so, it covers your conditions :)

That is not my issue actually, your code is pretty similar to mine, I'm wondering why serie12 is not displayed properly

@Q.Rey I do not clearly understand what you say about this but In my code i'll group of the 1 and 2 series and apply the filter so the result values change. The first group shows the series1 and series2 sum

I don't want any sum. Imagine i have 20 series, i want to group every similar series on the same scale. "Group" mean to have multiples series displayed on the same scale.
